# VBA not adding elements to a Solver model

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I had a problem earlier about solver not adding binary constraints to a model via VBA...I've (mostly) figured that one out.  But now I have a new problem.  First, let me post the relevant section of offending code.  I should note this is running in Excel 2007.

```
'build string of ByChange cells and set up cascading constraints
by_change_string = ""
For i = 1 To j - 1

    If Len(by_change_string) > 0 Then                   'there are already some elements in the string, so we might start with a comma
        If Not (Right(by_change_string, 1) = ",") Then  'make sure the last character isn't already a comma
            by_change_string = by_change_string & ","
        End If
    End If

    current_status = Sheets("Buyback Risk Area").Range("C1").Offset(i).Value
    Select Case current_status
        Case "Y"                'risk area is currently yellow, so green transition is available
            by_change_string = by_change_string & "$E$" & i + 1
            solverok setcell:="$B$" & j + 4, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=by_change_string

            'add binary constraints
            solveradd cellref:="$E$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
        Case "O"                'risk area is currently orange, so green and yellow transitions are available
            by_change_string = by_change_string & "$E$" & i + 1 & ",$G$" & i + 1
            solverok setcell:="$B$" & j + 4, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=by_change_string

            'add cascading constraints
            solveradd cellref:="$E$" & i + 1, relation:=1, formulatext:="$G$" & i + 1 'says E <= G, which means you can't select green unless you've already selected yellow

            'add binary constraints
            solveradd cellref:="$E$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"'                solveradd cellref:="$G$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
        Case "R"                'risk area is currently red, so green, yellow, and orange transitions are available
            by_change_string = by_change_string & "$E$" & i + 1 & ",$G$" & i + 1 & ",$I$" & i + 1
            'solverok setcell:="$B$" & j + 4, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=by_change_string

            'add cascading constraints
            solveradd cellref:="$E$" & i + 1, relation:=1, formulatext:="$G$" & i + 1 'says E <= G, which means you can't select green unless you've already selected yellow
            solveradd cellref:="$G$" & i + 1, relation:=1, formulatext:="$I$" & i + 1 'says G <= I, which means you can't select yellow unless you've already selected orange

            'add binary constraints
            solveradd cellref:="$E$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
            solveradd cellref:="$G$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
            solveradd cellref:="$I$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
        Case "B"                'risk area is black, so green, yellow, orange and red transitions are avaailable
            by_change_string = by_change_string & "$E$" & i + 1 & ",$G$" & i + 1 & ",$I$" & i + 1 & ",$K$" & i + 1
            solverok setcell:="$B$" & j + 4, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=by_change_string

            'add cascading constraints
            solveradd cellref:="$E$" & i + 1, relation:=1, formulatext:="$G$" & i + 1 'says E <= G, which means you can't select green unless you've already selected yellow
            solveradd cellref:="$G$" & i + 1, relation:=1, formulatext:="$I$" & i + 1 'says G <= I, which means you can't select yellow unless you've already selected orange
            solveradd cellref:="$I$" & i + 1, relation:=1, formulatext:="$K$" & i + 1 'says K <= M, which means you can't select orange unless you've already selected red

            'add binary constraints
            solveradd cellref:="$E$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
            solveradd cellref:="$G$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
            solveradd cellref:="$I$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
            solveradd cellref:="$K$" & i + 1, relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
    End Select
Next i

'buyback amount constraint
solveradd cellref:="$O$" & j + 1, relation:=1, formulatext:="$B$" & j + 2

'set target cell
solverok setcell:="$B$" & j + 4, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=by_change_string

'set binary constraints
'binary_array = Split(by_change_string, ",")
'For i = 0 To UBound(binary_array)
'    solveradd cellref:=Range(binary_array(i)), relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
'Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

SolverSolve userFinish:=False
```

The basic idea here is to loop through the sheet and look at the data (which will change from execution to execution) and build the appropriate model.

THe string by_change_string contains the cell addresses of all the changing variables, which are all binary.  So as the code examines each line of the spreadsheet, it determines which cells on that line are available to be considered by the model and appends them to the string.

The multiple calls to solverok with the growing by_change_string are an attempt to solve an earlier problem where the binary constraints weren't being added to the model.  All of the <= constraints were, but not the binary ones.  It seems you can't constrain a variable to be binary until after it has been added to the model.  There used to be just a single solverok statement after the loop that constructs by_change_string was complete, but when I did it that way I got all of the <= constraints and none of the binary ones.

When this code runs on my test sheet, the resulting model should have 136 decision variables (by changing cells).  I've checked, and the by_change_string does in fact have 136 addresses in it.  But when I look in the solver dialog box, there are only the first 41.  I've stepped through the entire execution in debug mode and seen it call solverok after each iteration, but for some reason only the first 41 by change cells are there.  And there's nothing special about the row of data where things go wrong...it's not like it's the first instance of one of the select cases or something...

When solver runs on this abbreviated model, it returns a garbage solution that it says is optimal.  Basically it keeps everything the same, so that the final objective function value is the same as the starting one.

So then I tried something else...you'll notice a commented out block of code at the bottom:

```
'set binary constraints
'binary_array = Split(by_change_string, ",")
'For i = 0 To UBound(binary_array)
'    solveradd cellref:=Range(binary_array(i)), relation:=5, formulatext:="binary"
'Next i
```

The idea here was to make things much more efficient by getting all those solverok and solveradd statements out of the select cases.  By waiting until after the final solverok statement, all the variables are now in the model, so you should be ablto just step through the by_change_string and make each of those a binary variable.  That way you only need one solverok statement and you can get rid of all the solveradd's in the select cases.  So I commented out all of those solverok's and solveradd's in the select cases and ran the macro again.  I get no output from solver.  When I look at the solver dialog after running, both the target cell and the by changing cells fields are blank.  It's as if that last solverok statement had never been run.

So then I tried uncommenting all the solverok's, but leaving the solveradd's for the binary variables commented out.  I go back to getting only the first 41 decision variables.  The loop to set the binary constraints did it's job, but the solveradd's aren't getting the variables into the model.

I'm pretty much stumped at this point.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I assumed:

**The Solver only allows up to 255 characters in the By Changing Cells parameter.** If you don't believe me, try to add the cells you want manually. You will not be able to do it.

The maximum non-contiguous ranges you can pass the solver is 51 (assuming each group is only 1 cell with the format like `$A$1,` with 1 letter 1 number 2 dollar signs and 1 comma). If you try to add more manually, it will remove all the previous selections. Presumably doing it with code just ignores everything once you've met the length constraint.

To be honest, I'd never used the solver and have no idea how to access it through code. Regardless, you're trying to make it do something it is incapable of doing.

Now rather than just telling you it won't work, here is a possible (yet obnoxious in my opinion) work around. This is what I would try if I had to do what you're doing. Copy the values that matter into another location in your work book and set them next to each other so that you can pass them as a contiguous range. Once the solver has run, put your values back where they should be located.

Edit: [This limited documentation for Solver](http://www.utexas.edu/courses/lasdon/design3.htm) may be slightly outdated, but it states the following:

> Model decision variables are entered in the By Changing Cells edit
> box. Excel allows one to enter a so-called multiple selection, which
> consists of up to 16 ranges (rectangles, rows or columns, or single
> cells) separated by commas.

This implies that you can only have 16 non-contiguous ranges to the Solver, and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Cook seems to be right about the cause of the issue. I'd propose a different workaround though. Create a named range that includes all of the non-contiguous ranges, and set by_change_string to a string representing that named range.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to add to these answers :

1. Going over the maximum value with code leaves you with an empty Bychange area in the model.
2. Naming a range will not solve the problem, as the Solver will translate it in its usual language immediately and delete the last ranges that can't fit in the window.

Source : I've just tried these solutions with excel 2013